# Data relationship diagram with D3

Tags: d3.js, extjs

I am using Sencha extJS D3 and need to object relationship diagram like the one below. I can create a horizontal tree but that does not allow the leafs to converge to a common object. Note that there are five columns of objects. Can Sencha do this?
[entity relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnzFW.png)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: That is my problem. I don't see a starting place. Sencha has a wrapper around D3 and has created a tree class. But a tree's branches do not converge. So back to, can D3 show an entity relationship diagram. Perhaps using d3-force or some other type?

Comment: @SteveJones, is it possible you could simplify this problem a little bit... maybe give us an entity relationship for something smaller, and then maybe that'll help you understand how to build something more complex?  It also sounds like you want to try and use associations through models, as that's usually what ER diagrams relate to, but you're talking more about trees here, so that's where my confusion lies with this question.

Comment: It does look like a tree but the branches converge at the leafs. The most simple would be a root having two children. Each of those children converge to the same grandchild. It looks like the d3-force could do that. Now just need to figure out how to turn those circles into rectangles with text in them.

Comment: @SteveJones, I think I see what you're talking about, but I'm not sure how they could converge to the same grandchild... unless your data contains the same record.  Could you provide some sample data for the simple example you just mentioned?  I think that'd help immensely.